# How do I reconfigure views to not use the defaultContainer in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a view that I need to dynamically create and insert into an Ember app ( off master - v1.0.0-rc.3-178-ge031b24 ) , and recently this view has started producing the notice:

> DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported.
>   [defaultContainer#lookup]

I've made some attempts to modify what I'm doing to rectify my implementation, but I haven't been able to find what I need to do.

currently, I'm attaching a new ViewContainer to the controller on route setup:

```
App.ThingRoute = Em.Route.extend
  setupDetailContainers: (controller) ->
    controller.set('imageContainer', Em.ContainerView.create())
    controller.get('imageContainer').appendTo(App.rootElement)
```

Then in the controller, when they click an image thumbnail the full size is inserted with:

```
showFullImage: (image) ->
  image_full = image.asset_url.replace(':size', 'original')
  container = @get('imageContainer')
  container.pushObject App.ShowImageView.create({image: image_full})
```

Any guidance on the correct way to do this, in order to remove deprecation warnings would be appreciated.

Comment: what ember version are you using?

Comment: Aw, sorry v1.0.0-rc.3-178-ge031b24 ( essentially today's master ), didn't realize I hadn't included that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a same problem, but before the deprecation message, so Ember was throwing an error.

Look here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2597

The bottom line is that you need to use `createChildView` inside of the view you will be creating the child in so that proper parent - children hierarchy is created.

Comment: "The bottom line is that you need to use createChildView inside of the view you will be creating the child in so that proper parent" - I don't really understand this. My container is this: App.LayoutContainer. I tried this: App.LayoutContainer.createChildView(App[index]); where index is something like: "App.HeaderView", a View instance. But this is not enough, because the dynamic views are created, but none is added as a child to the container.

Answer (score 1):

I started running into this problem after updating to v1.0.0-rc.3-292-g39e9ef7.  For me the problem arose from defining a `childView`using `create()` rather than `extend()`.  For example, I had done:

```
App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'fooTemplate'
    , childViews: ['barView']
    , barView: Ember.View.create({
        ... bindings and stuff ....
    })
    .... more and more ....
});
```

... and the notice I was receiving went away when I changed the line:

```
    , barView: Ember.View.create({
```

... to:

```
    , barView: Ember.View.extend({
```

Hope this helps others who might hit this notice from a similar set of circumstances.